# How to integrate Spring security 3 with jboss realms and user roles?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jboss, spring-security

How would I get Authentication and roles information from a JBoss realm that uses kerberos/SPNEGO from MSAD into a web-app using Spring security 3?  Do I need to create a custom AuthenticationProvider or UserdetailsService?  I've noticed that Spring Security 2 had container adapters, but they decided it was too much of a pain to keep them up.  The other alternative that I can see is to call back out using LDAP.  But, shouldn't there be an easier way?

The main point is the app is deployed in a single sign-on environment, but we'd need to enable/disable certain functionality based on the user roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider as your authentication provider.